# How to accelerate vertical scrolling in Safari on iPhones

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, css, safari

The same page (e.g. http://mobile.nytimes.com) scrolls very slow on Safari/iPhone, but really fast in Chrome/Adnroid.

But I found at least one page (http://www.blick.ch) that scrolls very fast on iPhones too.

How can I achieve the same effect for my page? - Javascript solutions would be ok too!